# Wordpress change message on register form

Tags: wordpress

I found code to change the message on the login page:

```
function awsm_login_message( $message ) {
    if ( empty($message) ){
        return "<p class='message'>Word een AardeWijze klas en meld je aan!</p>";
    } else {
        return $message;
    }
}
add_filter( 'login_message', 'awsm_login_message' );
```

But I need to change the message on the register form and I can only add text in the body of the form with `register_form` hook. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by using the same filter but checking which action is requested, you can change the message accordingly. Using your code as base:

```
function awsm_login_message( $message ) {
    $action = isset( $_REQUEST['action'] ) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : '';

    if ( empty($message) ){
        if ($action == 'register') 
            return "<p class='message'>Message to register</p>";
        else 
            return "<p class='message'>Word een AardeWijze klas en meld je aan!</p>";
    } else {
        return $message;
    }
}
add_filter( 'login_message', 'awsm_login_message' );
```

[WordPress Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_message/#user-contributed-notes)